# SNOWFLAKE SQL turn column values into row based off of ID

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Hi I am using snowflake and have a player table
[image]

I have the ID and Player Columns in the table and I am trying to list all of the players in one row based off of the ID value.

So for example ID 1610612748 will only have one row and all of the players listed in the player column on that row delimited by a comma.

Comment: Can you provide some example results? what are you expecting to see?

Comment: @SimonDarr Hi Simon yes I am expecting to see the following:
id|Player
1610612748 | 1625407,1628972...ect 

I want all of the Players in one row based off of ID

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [LIST_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html) aggregate function. Something like this should work:

**Create example table:**

```sql
create or replace transient table test_table(id number, player number) as
select
    column1 as id,
    column2 as player
from
values
       (1610612748, 123),
       (1610612748, 231),
       (1610612748, 333),
       (1610612748, 321),
       (1111111111, 123),
       (1111111111, 421),
       (2222222222, 123)
;
```

**Run Query**

```sql
select
    id,
    listagg(player ,',')
from test_table
group by id
```

**Results**

```
+----------+--------------------+
|ID        |LISTAGG(PLAYER ,',')|
+----------+--------------------+
|1111111111|123,421             |
|2222222222|123                 |
|1610612748|123,231,333,321     |
+----------+--------------------+
```